# What's wrong :lxml.html.parse in google app

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

Here is my app.yaml:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app

libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: latest
```

Here is helloworld.py:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
import lxml.html

down = "http://sc.hkex.com.hk/gb/www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm"
file = urlfetch.fetch(down)
print file.content

root = lxml.html.parse(file.content)
data = root.xpath('//tr[@class="tr_normal"]/td[position()=1]')
name = [row.text_content() for row in data]

for code in name:
    print code
```

When I run:

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py helloworld/
```

I open `127.0.0.1:8080` and I can  see  the website `http://sc.hkex.com.hk/gb/www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm` but there is wrong output from the line `print file.content`.

May you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: i do not think lxml is even present at GAE.

Answer (score 1):

lxml is a C module, GAE only supports pure python modules so it's not supported.